# How to evaluate SymPy expressions with indexed variables using explicit values?

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have a summation using sympy

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
m = 10
n = IndexedBase('n')
i = symbols("i",cls=Idx)
sum_ = summation(n[i],[i,1,m])
sum_
>>> n[10] + n[1] + n[2] + n[3] + n[4] + n[5] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8] + n[9]
```

and a numpy array of values

```
a = np.random.random((m,))
```

I want to evaluate `sum_` using each corresponding value of `a` - so for example `n[1]` would be `a[0]`, `n[2]` would be `a[1]` and so on. How do I pass the values of `a` into `n`?

I have tried using the `doit()` method, but I am unsure how that works, and keep getting errors.

Furthermore, let's say I have a complicated function which contains sums and that I want to take derivatives of and then evaluate for specific values of the coefficients and variables as below

```
theta0 = Symbol('theta0')
theta1 = Symbol('theta1')
theta2 = Symbol('theta2')
sigma = Symbol('sigma')
sigma0 = Symbol('sigma0')
sigma1 = Symbol('sigma1')
sigma2 = Symbol('sigma2')
x = IndexedBase('x')
t = IndexedBase('t')
i = symbols("i", cls=Idx)

nges = -(1/(2*sigma**2))*summation( (x[i] - theta0 - theta1*t[i] - 
theta2*t[i]**2)**2, [i, 1, 2])
func = (-1/2)*((theta0/sigma0)**2 + (theta1/sigma1)**2 + 
(theta2/sigma2)**2) + nges

diff(func, theta0, 1)
>>> -1.0*theta0/sigma0**2 - (4*theta0 + 2*theta1*t[1] + 2*theta1*t[2] + 2*theta2*t[1]**2 + 2*theta2*t[2]**2 - 2*x[1] - 2*x[2])/(2*sigma**2)
```

How would I pass in scalar values for the `theta`'s and vectors (numpy arrays) for the `x`'s and `t`'s? (I tried using `.limit()`, but this got cumbersome as I had to call it multiple times on one expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `.subs`, passing in a dictionary of substitutions.

```
sum_.subs({n[i+1]: a[i] for i in range(m)})
```

In some cases you will want to also invoke `evalf` to get any symbolic constants like `pi` evaluated. In this case it's recommended to include substitutions into `evalf` like this:

```
sum_.evalf(subs={n[i+1]: a[i] for i in range(m)})
```

Similarly for your second example. It's more convenient to prepare a dict with values first.

```
values = {theta0: 0.2, theta1: 0.3, theta2: 1.3, sigma0: 2, sigma: 2.2}
values.update({t[i]: 3*i for i in range(1, 3)})
values.update({x[i]: 5*i for i in range(1, 3)})
diff(func, theta0, 1).subs(values)   # 9.67809917355372
```